# Castor generates long variables for elements who are declared as Integer in xsd, how to correct the behavior and generate Integer variables?

Tags: integer, long-integer, castor

Castor version used is 1.4.1. The Java classes contain long variables of Integer elements(from xsd) after generation by castor libraries